# Regex to parse CSS file: will this expression work

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to Regular Expressions and I am attempting to parse a CSS file and extract all ids and classes CSS implementation.

Will my regular expression below correctly extract all classes and ids? Is there a better regular expression I can use to grab all ids and class CSS implementation?

```
string cssCode = "some css code";
MatchCollection ids = Regex.Matches(cssCode, "#(.*?) {(.*?)}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection classes = Regex.Matches(cssCode, ".(.*?){(.*?)}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

My methodology is:
- For each `#` character, ignore the text after the `#` char, if we find a `{` next then I know its CSS implementation so grab everything from `{` to the next `}`.

Comment: What about `#myId:first{}`. Also, you should use: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Have you tried running that regex against a sample CSS? What were the results?

Answer (score 0):

These might work:

```
/\.([\w\d\.-]+)[^{}]*{[^}]*}/ // for classes
/#([\w\d\.-]+)[^{}]*{[^}]*}/ // for ids
```

I tried them with javascript on a couple of stylesheet pages, and it seemed to work. I don't know if it's missing any, but I know it's not getting anything that shouldn't be there.